# How to get the current "url" of a page using useLocation from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am currently trying to understand the url path of the current page of a react project using 'react-router-dom'. I want to print the url of the current location of the page I'm navigating.

This is how did it.

```
export default function useQuery () {
  const { search } = useLocation()

  return React.useMemo(() => new URLSearchParams(search), [search])
}
```

```
const query = useQuery()
console.log(query)
```

I want to know is there another method that i can print the current url path of the navigating page or can i use the `useLocation` method to find it.

PS: I'm using 'react-router-dom' version 5

Comment: Your question title and body don't agree on topic or make sense. The title states you want to get the URL, but the body only references the queryString. Do you need the full and complete URL, or just the URL path, e.g. `location.pathname`, or just the queryString, e.g. `location.search` like in your post? Please [edit] to clarify what specifically you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are several ways you can print the current URL path of the navigating page. One way is to use the `window.location.pathname` property to get the path portion of the current URL.

```
console.log(window.location.pathname);
```

If you're using React and React Router, you can also use the useLocation hook to get the current location object, which includes the pathname.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  console.log(location.pathname);
}
```

Comment: I used both of them. But it keeps printing  "/" in the console.

Comment: if you don't wanna to see "/" , put this code window.location.pathname.substring(1)

Comment: actually what i'm saying is it does not print anything beside "/" .

Comment: then you do not have pathname, this gives you from url https://stackoverflow.com/questions as a path "/questions"

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the React Router, you should be able to use the useLocation() method to get all of the route properties.

```
const location = useLocation();
const { hash, pathname, search } = location;
```

Otherwise you can simply use the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object that is automatically injected in all browsers
`window.location.pathname`

If you're using the HashRouter, you should read the hash property